# Synonym of "health recovery phase"

Tags: phrase-request

A successfully big operation is often followed by a period of "health recovery phase" which sometimes needs at least 1 month.

What's another phrase I could use? Does "health restoration phase" sound natural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Recuperation*** (derived from the same Latin word which descended through French to give us *recover*) is the general term; here's what the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary has to say:

> **1** [intransitive] **recuperate (from something)**
> to get back your health, strength or energy after being ill/sick, tired,  injured, etc.
> SYNONYM recover
> *He's still recuperating from his operation.*
> *After an exhausting few weeks I needed some time to recuperate.*
>
> **recuperation**
> NOUN [uncountable]
> *It was a period of rest and recuperation.*

*Recuperation* usually signifies a relatively passive process of waiting for the body to heal itself. ***Rehabilitation*** is employed when active therapies are required to recover function or restore someone to health.

Answer (score 4):

As alternative also **convalescence** can be used, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convalescence:

> Convalescence is the gradual recovery of health and strength after
>   illness. It refers to the later stage of an infectious disease or
>   illness when the patient recovers and returns to normal, but may
>   continue to be a source of infection even if feeling better. In this
>   sense, "recovery" can be considered a synonymous term. This also
>   sometimes includes patient care after a major surgery, under which
>   they are required to visit the doctor for regular check-ups.

And this article gives the alternative **recovery**, which you already named yourself.